# Gnome/X logs off immediately after login -- which logfiles are relevant?

Tags: gnome, login, authentication, fingerprint-reader

I've been tinkering with `fingerprint-gui` as well as `X`/`xrandr` resolution settings.

When I start my machine, it boots up normally. As soon as `X` and `gnome` have finished starting, it logs me off automatically and brings me back to the `gdm` login prompt with the user list. Then I am, however, able to log in using "Ubuntu Desktop Fail-safe".

I've checked the list of start-up applications, but everything seems fine there.

I can't yet put my finger on what exactly might be responsible for this: `X`, `gnome` or some messed up `pam.d` settings. So far I've checked `/var/logs/X11/xorg.0.log`, `/var/logs/auth.log` and `~/.xsession-errors`. In addition, I don't quite seem to understand the "interplay" between X, GDM, GNOME, GNOME-policykit, PAM.d and all that.

**Are there any other relevant log files that could point me to what's broken?**

**Specs:**

- Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat
- IBM/Lenovo Thinkpad R60, ATI Radeon x1400 Mobility
- all updates installed
- Linux User 1 year+,

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 10):

For posterity - I'll leave a solution here...

This can happen if you try and run an X server under root privilege while logged in to your account... so you could have typed:

sudo startx

or were messing with xauth as root.

This will create a file in your home directory ~/.Xauthority which is owned by root.

When you try to login the system will try to read this file but will not have permission and log you back out.

The solution is to

- go out to a terminal Ctrl+Alt+F1
- log in to your account
- type: sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/old.Xauthority
- now log out by typing "logout"
- get back to dm with Ctrl+Atl+F7
- you should be able to log in now!

If you don't have sudo privilege, you have to get someone who does on your system

Comment: Awesome. If I had as much rep as I have on other SE sites, you would get instantly a bounty on this answer! I just spend several hours; re-installing all gnome packages, reconfiguring everything to default, removing caches and settings, playing around with lightdm, and so on and so on and so on... I was banging my head why a guest-sessions worked and I couldn't log in properly. Thank you, thank you, thank you! And of course +1

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an ancient question but it just happened to me.  It turned out that the last line of my ~/.profile was returning a non-zero exit code.  Since the bash 'source' command returns as its exit code the last exit code of the script sourced, I imagine this upset the xsession init.

You may see evidence of this in ~/.xsession-errors (I did), but then you might not if your last profile command returns an error code without printing any output.

So take a look at the bottom of each of your login scripts.  Worked for me.

Comment: The .profile did it for me. Good call thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the log files it's difficult to say where the bug comes(use pastebin.ubuntu.com or report a new bug to Launchpad by running `ubuntu-bug xorg-server`, but try look gdm's logs at /var/log/gdm/ (that folder may not be accessible without root access).

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me recently. I solved my issue by looking in the lightdm logs (`/usr/log/lightdm/*`). In my case, it was trying to load a session called `gnome-shell` when none existed.  I copied `/usr/share/xsession/gnome.session` to `/usr/share/xsession/gnome-shell.session` and things worked out fine.

(Note, I realize that this probably would not work for the asker, as Ubuntu wasn't using LightDM in 10.10.  However, if the question had been asked today, or if someone searches today, this is a likely answer.)

Answer (score 0):

it might happen that your `PATH` variable is messed up. To fix the issue:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in login screen

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Now log back in to the front screen and try to login.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me (on Xfce) after copying a .mov file to the Desktop. Using ssh to remote login and deleting the file resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Okay Guys, I found the real solution to this problem, for all those who have the NVIDIA graphics cards installed.

The best solution is to uninstall the Nvidia drivers. 
( But I recommend using their driver .run file to uninstall 
simply doing: ***sudo apt purge nvidia-*-***  etc. did not work for me )

During installation on my system I had downloaded the latest nvidia-driver as a .run file from their website: 
http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-archive.html

I had the .run file saved in ~/Downloads as ***nvidia-drivers.run***

Once in the login screen, i did the steps below:

1. ctrl+alt+f6
2. login
3. sudo service lightdm stop
4. cd to ~/Downloads directory where nvidia-drivers.run file is stored.
5. ***sudo nvidia-drivers.run --uninstall***
6. sudo service lightdm restart

See step5: This will properly uninstall all the Nvidia drivers and you can immediately log back in. Good Luck !