# Logged out right after login after docker install

Tags: 16.04, login, logout, docker

My computer was fine a working properly until I tried to install Docker. Everything looked like it went well. It was successfully installed and running the hello world worked. I then went on to the extra configuration steps to Manage Docker as a non-root user (https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)

I ran

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Then moved on to step 4. It said log out and back in, but I installed a bounch of things and I like to restart my computer to reset any caches and to have everything running smoothly (I don't think restarted instead of just logging out was the issue).

When the computer came back on, and I already noticed something different. Usually when I boot into the computer, once I get to the log in screen my second moniter usually turns on and it wasn't turning on at all. I thought that maybe it would just turn on once I logged in (as one of the monitors was on). Once I log in a black screen pops really quickly with 1 line on the top of text but it too quick to read(looks like it was loading user settings or something) then pops back to the log in screen, and when It pops my back to log in screen it mutes the sound (as I see the mute sound image).

Things I have tried (from [I am logged out immediately after logging in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367260/i-am-logged-out-immediately-after-logging-in) and other sources):

1. Verified that it was still checking user credentials by typing in the wrong password.
2. logged in with (ctlr+alt+f1) and removed .Xauthority
3. logged in with (ctlr+alt+f1) and restarted lightdm
4. Both 2 and 3 together
5. I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and unity and restarted and tried again.
6. logged in with (ctlr+alt+f1) then I looked to see who owned the home directory of my user (as someone suggested) and is owned by the user I am trying to log in as.
7. As login as guest is enabled, I tried to log in as the guest instead and had the same issue.

I am not really sure how to solve this so any help would be appreciated. Few extra notes: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I followed the instructions exactly on the page I linked above for my version for installing docker. Before I installed anything I just powered my computer on and with no issue so it couldn't have been something that wasn't while I was installing docker.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that when I installed the packages with docker it messed up something with my graphics driver (not sure how). After re-installing my graphics drivers everything seemed to work fine.

here is where I found a solution that actually worked: [login loop after upgrade to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760492/login-loop-after-upgrade-to-16-04#answer-821972)