# Immediate logoff after login on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, login, lightdm, upstart, xserver

I try to quickly summarize the problem and what happened (details about system are below). I know there exist [many](https://askubuntu.com/q/367260) [similar](https://askubuntu.com/q/20929) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/944397/445311) however none of the answers did help in my case. I did not fiddle with any new drivers, applications, user privileges, file permissions or whatsoever. Also I did not start any graphical application via `sudo` or modified my `.profile` or `.bashrc` files. I did check the integrity of my `.Xauthority` file.

---

So when I (re-)start my computer it takes me to the login screen as always, however after entering my credentials (and some loading time) the screen turns black for like half a second and then I'm immediately logged off. During that very short period it also displays the following message:

```
/dev/sda7: clean, 659285/8429568 files, 7752992/33709961 blocks
```

**During the last (successful) session** I experienced a graphics bug, specifically when Alt+Tabbing it won't show the application tabs anymore (though the tabbing itself worked). I realized this when I wanted to tab out of Firefox (if that's important in any case). I wanted to get rid of this bug and so I restarted the computer. During that session my computer used lots of memory (more than the available 16GB) and hence was swapping out.

#### Error logs

I checked the `~/.xsession-errors` file and it has the following content:

```
X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2060) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2039) killed by TERM signal
upstart: logrotate main process (1859) killed by TERM signal
upstart: upstart-dbus-session-bridge main process (1932) terminated with status 1
upstart: upstart-notifier-release main process (1934) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (2037) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2028) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2077) killed by TERM signal
upstart: window-stack-bridge main process (1884) killed by KILL signal
```

There are lots of log files in `/var/log/lightdm` with lots of content but since I don't know what I should be looking for I didn't seek through all of them.

#### System

- Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
- Kernel: 4.4.0-134-generic

I run a NVIDIA graphics card which (I suppose) is used by default for graphics output (at least it was the last time I checked). Running `lspci -k` reveals:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
[...]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
[...]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

---

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Based on this similar error log [With Intel HD graphics, X_GLXCreateContext only works as root](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=217752) I wonder if you have a `LD_PRELOAD` (or related `LD_` variable) in your environment that's messing things up? Can you log in to a CLI virtual terminal (CTRL-ALT-F2 etc.) and run `printenv | grep LD_` from there?

Comment: @steeldriver I just checked and I just have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set (which looks fine). Actually I managed to log back in by removing all NVIDIA related stuff from my system (`nvidia-*.run --uninstall`, which complained about a broken installation but continued nevertheless and then `apt purge nvidia*`; upon restart I was asked to restore x-config which failed though). When I try to reinstall any of the nvidia drivers via `.run` it complains about no compatible graphics card found and when I install via `apt` then after reboot the screen is just black. Maybe my graphics card is broken?